# jQuery - Take array of objects, then sort based on a dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have a game I created that will add questions missed to my array `missedArr`, in my **[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bLvxq6jt/9/)**, I have 2 buttons (both set to be wrong answers). After clicking these, it seems to have stored both clicks correctly, however I want give a readout at the end of the game to show my user what parts they did well on vs ones they did poorly on.

To do this, I created a function called `determineScorecard` which should serve to create a dict of my `missedArr`, however, when it goes to trigger I get undefined.

The `dSc` function should be sorting across the `data-category` set on the html buttons, then I want to console.log only the ones that were missed in `category-2`

```
function determineScorecard (){

    //build dictionary for missed questions

    var sortedMissed = {};
    for( var i = 0, max = missedArr.length; i < max ; i++ ){
        if( sortedMissed[missedArr[i].category] == undefined ){
            sortedMissed[missedArr[i].category] = [];
        }
        sortedMissed[missedArr[i].category].push(missedArr[i]);
    }

    console.log(sortedMissed["2"]);    
}
```

I can't seem to get this to split up correctly.

Comment: @Taplar I fixed the issue with `type` vs `category`. By sorting, I mean more of accessing the array and pulling it apart based on the `category`. For instance, if there were 4 missed answers, and 2 of them belonged to `category2`, I want to be able to see that/print it for the user

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the typo. The goal is to be able to see that this user missed X answers total, Y answers from cat 2, Z answers from cat 1. So then at the end I can give them a scorecard that says they missed `x answers total`, `y answers in cat 2` and `z answers in cat 1`. Then I'll be able to recommend them a link based on the category they struggled the most in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```js
var missedArr = [];
$('.answer').click(function(){
  var da=$(this).data();
  if (da.correct) return false;
  missedArr.push(da);
  determineScorecard();
});
function determineScorecard (){
    var sortedMissed = {};
    $.each(missedArr,(i,da)=>{
      if( sortedMissed[da.category] === undefined ){
            sortedMissed[da.category] = [];
      }
      sortedMissed[da.category].push(da);
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedMissed));    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger answer" data-category="2" data-question="2" data-value="300" data-correct="false">Google</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger answer" data-category="3" data-question="2" data-value="300" data-correct="false">Full-circle reporting</button>
```

In my solution I have not stored the whole `button`DOM elements but only their `data()`-objects into the `sortedMissed` array since these contain all the information about the question and button pressed. But if you don't like it, feel free to change that back again ...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I didn't realize I could only store the data objects. Awesome tip to know in the future. Thanks!

Comment: this is exactly what I did, no?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is! I only noticed after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
var incorrect = [];

$('.answer').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).data(),
        correct = data.correct;

  if(!data.correct){
    incorrect.push(data);

    determineScorecard();
  }
});

function determineScorecard(){
  var missed = {};

  for(var i = 0, max = incorrect.length; i < max ; i++){
    var question = incorrect[i];

    if(!missed[question.category]){
      missed[question.category] = [];
    }

    missed[question.category].push(question);
  }

  console.log(missed);    
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/84sp06ju/)

However, I don't see how this can produce what you're expecting. The scorecard logic makes zero sense to me (with the code that's been provided). Can you post a complete example with the questions so we can see the entire flow?

Comment: This seems to be more in-line with what I'm looking for. As of right now I don't have it finalized as I'm adding new features to an existing problem. But basically there will always be 6 questions in each category and if I can see the ones they got missed, I'll be able to do some quick math to determine a percentage for that category

Answer (score -1):

Referencing your JSFiddle: The missedArr array contains DOM elements. To get the category, value, etc of that element you'll need to access the dataset property of the element.

```
missedArr[i].category // doesn't exist

missedArr[i].dataset.category // should exist
```

Updated for jQuery, which uses the .data() method:

```
   missedArr[i].data('category') // should exist
```

When wrapping 'this' in the jQuery function like $(this), the element becomes a jQuery object, so to access the dataset use the .data() method rather than trying to access the properties directly like you would with vanilla JS:

```
    // lines 22 - 24 of your JSFiddle
    if( sortedMissed[missedArr[i].category] == undefined ){
        sortedMissed[missedArr[i].category] = [];
    }
```